# Синтаксический анализ предложения

Tags: синтаксис, семантика, смысл

Переформулирую вопрос: разъясните, пожалуйста, синтаксис предложения *"Дорога — обустроенная или приспособленная и используемая для движения транспортных средств полоса земли."*

А именно:

1. К чему относится определение *для движения транспортных средств*?
   Только к слову *используемая*, к двум словам *приспособленная* и
   *используемая*, или ко всем трём — *обустроенная или приспособленная и
   используемая*?
2. Союз *и* связывает только слова *приспособленная* и *используемая*
   или *обустроенная* тоже?

Другими словами, можно ли фразу
    *"обустроенная или приспособленная и используемая"* переиначить
    так: *"обустроенная и используемая или приспособленная и
    используемая"*?

Comment: Здесь задания не выполняют. Здесь обсуждаются проблемы языка.

Comment: Здесь речь идет о неясном определении, грамматику которого можно толковать различным образом. Но лучший вариант - это избавиться от лишнего слова:   Дорога - обустроенная или приспособленная  для движения транспортных средств полоса земли

Comment: Это выдержка из ПДД, поэтому от слов, даже лишних, к сожалению не избавиться. Что еще хуже, все и каждый на территории РФ обязаны уметь однозначно трактовать эти корявые конструкции

Comment: @shampar это не задание, а вопрос, заданный по ссылке "задать вопрос", которая находится в главном меню **этого** сайта. А вот ссылки "обсудить проблему языка" я здесь как раз не вижу

Comment: Мне кажется, что грамматика такая: Дорога - (обустроенная или приспособленная) и используемая для движения транспортных средств полоса земли." Два первых определения связывает союз ИЛИ, а затем союз И соединяет эту пару с третьим определением. Но выбор сделан по смыслу, сама грамматика читается неоднозначно, что и плохо.

Comment: Спасибо, Arina, за ваш ответ. Правильно ли я понял, что руководствуясь только правилами языка и не прибегая к помощи конструкций вроде "думаю, что здесь имелось ввиду..." невозможно однозначно определить структуру этого предложения?

Comment: Грамматику этого предложения можно определить только исходя из значений трех определений. Конечно, в языке встречаются такие варианты, когда семантика помогает определять грамматику,  но в тексте делового стиля важна точность и ясность. Поэтому предложение нуждается в правке, а исправить  что-либо здесь сложно, так как сочетание "для движения транспортных средств" относится ко всем трем определениям. Поэтому надо действовать радикально: какую  необходимую информацию передает слово "используемая" , неужели без него нельзя обойтись?

Answer (score 1):

Формально возможно двоякое прочтение:

1. Дорога — (обустроенная или приспособленная) и используемая для движения транспортных средств полоса земли.
2. Дорога — обустроенная или (приспособленная и используемая для движения транспортных средств) полоса земли.

Но добавив немного здравого смысла, легко понять, что имеется в виду первый варинат.

Answer (score 1):

> **Дорога — обустроенная или приспособленная и используемая для движения транспортных средств полоса земли.**

Здесь нужно чуть аккуратнее объяснить, что имеется в виду. 
Обустроенная дорога — это полоса земли, на которую нанесено дорожное покрытие, разметка, ограждение и т.п. (не обязательно всё перечисленное).
Приспособленная дорога — это какая-то (не оборудованная специальным образом) полоса земли, приспособленная под движение транспортных средств. Например, грунтовая дорога ("грунтовка").

И та и другая дорога может быть использована для движения транспортных средств.

Я бы оформил данное предложение следующим образом:

**Дорога — обустроенная или приспособленная полоса земли, которая используется для движения транспортных средств.**